# Create struct that is usable with sqlx, has a datetime AND is serializable. Or how to enable serde?

Tags: rust, serde, rust-sqlx

I have a struct that contains a date and I use it with [sqlx](https://github.com/launchbadge/sqlx) to retrieve data from my database. So something like:

```
use sqlx::types::chrono::{DateTime, Utc};

pub struct Account {
    pub id: i32,
    pub primary_email_id: i32,
    pub created: DateTime<Utc>,
}
```

and

```
sqlx::query_as!(Account, "select * ...")
```

This works fine so far. But I also want `Account` to be serializable via serde. The obvious approach is:

```
#[derive(Serialize)]
pub struct Account {
    ...
```

This fails, because the `Serialize` trait is not implemented for `DateTime<Utc>`. I tried the same with `PrimitiveDateTime` from the `time` crate with the same result. In theory both should support `serde` as a feature.

I tried to explicitly add `time` or `chrono` as dependency, to enable `serde` as feature and use the type without the `sqlx::types` prefix. But in that case it fails because some `sqlx` traits are not implemented.

I assume that I somehow have to enable the serde feature for the classes brought in by sqlx, but I have no idea how to specify a feature for a feature!?

How to I tell sqlx to enable serde for the time/chrono types?

Comment: chrono is a reexport and recent chrono version have a serde feature so just add chrono as dependancies and add serde feature should work

Comment: Correct. If you would make it an answer, I could accept it.

Answer (score 2):

I was able to solve it by importing `chrono` separately from `sqlx` and enabling `serde` for it:

`Cargo.toml`:

```
sqlx = { version = "0.6.2", features = ["runtime-actix-native-tls", "postgres"] }
chrono = { version = "0.4.23", features = ["serde"] }
```

And then you will need to change your `use` declaration from
`use sqlx::types::chrono::{DateTime, Utc};` to `use chrono::{DateTime, Utc};`

Answer (score 1):

This depends on the `time` and `chrono` Cargo features of `sqlx`. So ensure the `[dependencies]` section of your `Cargo.toml` file includes these. As an example:

```
sqlx = { version = "0.6.0", features = [ "postgres", "runtime-tokio-native-tls", "offline", "time", "chrono" ] }
```

(This is essentially the comment of @Stargateur above. All credit to them.)